# Which waiver to apply

Tags: visas, usa

What is i192 waiver for?
and who need to apply that waiver?

who need to apply i212 waiver?

Please explain in brief about them .

Please Advice

Thank you

Comment: Although these forms are waivers and they're used in conjunction with applying for visas, they have nothing to do with the Visa Waiver Program.  I changed the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both I-192 and I-212 are applications to be allowed into the US despite being **inadmissible** - in other words, if you would not normally be allowed in.

I-192 is mainly for if you are inadmissible on health grounds or because of a criminal record, I-212 is for re-admission after previously being deported or removed from the US.

Both of these require you to have a very good reason (an example might be you're inadmissible on health grounds, but need treatment that's only available in the US). If you do plan to file one of these, you probably want to speak to an immigration lawyer in your country.

If you're actually looking for the [Visa Waiver Program](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visa-waiver-program.html), which lets nationals of certain countries enter the US without a visa, then as Nate Eldredge says, that's totally unrelated.

Comment: I-192 is basically only for Canadian citizens to apply for a nonimmigrant waiver. Any other nationality would apply for a nonimmigrant waiver as part of applying for a nonimmigrant visa, and there is no specific form for the waiver.